# Product of ordinals notation

Tags: notation, ordinals

How to denote product of ordinals: $\cdot$ or $\times$?

I'm not sure which of these two multiplication symbols to use.

Comment: Juxtaposition, usually ($\alpha\beta$), unless both are finite ordinals, in which case you are just doing the usual multiplication.

Comment: Don’t use $\times$. In my experience $\cdot$ is customary, though juxtaposition is also seen.

Answer (score 2):

The use of $ \times $ would be easily confused with the cartesian product, so it's not being used. I've seen both $ \alpha \cdot \beta $ and $ \alpha \beta $.